# python - ldap -how can I use ldap module by not importing python ldap module

Tags: python-ldap

Where can I get source code for python ldap module . I want to integrate with my python code to use ldap module (but donot want to install separtely or import)

-shijo

Answer (score 0):

The source code is available at the official Python-LDAP website: http://python-ldap.sourceforge.net.

It can be checked out from CVS.